# How to draw an exact 1 monitor pixel line using drawingContext in OnRender for a 120 DPI resolution?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawingcontext, onrender

I just cannot manage to draw a single pixel wide black (!) line in `OnRender` using `drawingContext.DrawLine()` on my laptop monitor which has a DPI of 120. I face this problems since years and I read many answers here on stackoverflow, but I can simply not get a working code. Many answers link to this article: [wpftutorial.net: Draw On Physical Device Pixels](http://wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html). It recommends to use Guidelines and to offset them by half a pixel, i.e. setting y=10.5 instead of the desired position 10 for a 96 DPI monitor. But it doesn't explain how to do the calculation for different DPIs.

WPF uses logical units (LU) which are 1/96 inch wide, meaning drawingContext.DrawLine(Width: 1) wants to draw a line 1/96 inch wide. The pixels of my monitor are 1/120 inch wide.

The article only says that the line width for 120 DPI should not be 1 LU, but 0.8 LU, which is 1/120 inch, the width of a pixel from my monitor.

Should accordingly the offset be 0.4 instead of 0.5 ? This makes the whole coordinate calculation very complicated. Let's say I want to draw a line on 5 LU, i.e. 5/96 inch which is at 0.0520 inch. The nearest monitor pixel would be number 6 which is at 0.05 inch. Meaning the correction would need to be 0.25 LU. But if I want to draw a line at 6 LU, the offset would need to be would be 0.5.

One problem I can see right away is that my code cannot be sure that the coordinates 0, 0 are precisely on a real monitor pixel.  If the parent control puts my control on an uneven number of LU, then 0,0 would not precisely align with a monitor pixel, meaning I have no chance to calculate for a particular LU what its offset should be.

So I thought, what the heck, I just try to draw 10 lines, for each increasing its y by 0.1. The result (second row) looks like that:
[image: First row: perfect black 1 pixel line, second row: WPF lines]

The first row shows how a perfect 1 pixel wide, black line should look like, enlarged 8 times. The second row shows the line drawn by WPF:

```
Pen penB08 = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 0.8);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  drawingContext.DrawLine(penB08, new Point(i * 9, i*0.1), new Point(i * 9 + 5, i*0.1));
}
```

As you can tell, not one of them is precisely 1 pixel wide and therfore none of them is really black !

If the above mentioned article is right, at least one of the lines should display properly. Reason: the difference between 96 DPI and 120 DPI is 1/5. Meaning every 5th LU pixel should start at exactly the same position like a monitor pixel. The offset should be 1/2 LU, that's why I made 10 1/10 steps.

See below for other examples using guidelines as recommended in that article. As written in that article, it doesn't make a difference if one uses guidelines or works with offsets.

## Question

Please provide the **code** which truly draws a 1 pixel wide line on a 120 DPI monitor. I know, there are already many answers on stackoverflow which explain how it should be theoretically solved. Please also note that the code must run in `OnRender` using `drawingContext.DrawLine()` as opposed to using `Visual`, which has the properties like `SnapToDevicePixels` to address the problem.

## To all who are too eager to mark questions as dupplicate

I understand that duplicate questions are bad for stackoverflow. But often a question gets marked as duplicate, which is actually different and that then prevents the question being discussed. So if you think there is already an answer, please write a comment and give me a chance to check it. I will then run that code and enlarge it. Only then one can tell, if it really works.

## Things I tried already

I spent already a week trying all kind of variations to get the lines. None gave a black 1 monitor pixel line. All are grayish and more than 1 pixel wide.

### Using Visual Options

Clemens suggested using `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` and/or `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"`. Here is the result without or any combination of the options:

```
SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode((DependencyObject)this, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

[image: lines drawn using Visual options]

It seems `SnapsToDevicePixels` has no effect, but with `SetEdgeMode` the first 3 dashes are 1 pixel higher than the following 7 dashes, meaning aliasing seems to happen as desired, but the lines are still 2 or even 3 pixels wide and not properly black.

### Using Guidelines

[image: various ways to draw a line]

The very first line I painted in `paint.net` as a reference how a proper line should look like. Here is the code to generate the lines:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Sample {
  public partial class MainWindow: Window {

    GlyphDrawer glyphDrawerNormal;
    GlyphDrawer glyphDrawerBold;

    public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      Background = Brushes.Transparent;
      var dpi = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this);
      glyphDrawerNormal = new GlyphDrawer(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch, dpi.PixelsPerDip);
      glyphDrawerBold = new GlyphDrawer(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeights.Bold, FontStretch, dpi.PixelsPerDip);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {
      drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
      drawSampleLines(drawingContext);
    }

    Pen penB1 = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
    Pen penB08 = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 0.8);
    Pen penB05 = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 0.5);
    const double x0 = 10.0;
    const double x1 = 300.0; //line start
    const double x2 = 305.0;
    const int ySpacing = 18;
    const int lineOffset = -7;

    private void drawSampleLines(DrawingContext drawingContext) {
      var y = 30.0;
      glyphDrawerNormal.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "Perfect, 1 pix y step", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      y += 2*ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerBold.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "Line samples with 1 logical unit width pen", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      y += ySpacing;
      drawLineSet(drawingContext, ref y, penB1);
      y += 2*ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerBold.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "Line samples with 0.8 logical unit width pen", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      y += ySpacing;
      drawLineSet(drawingContext, ref y, penB08);
      y += 2*ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerBold.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "Line samples with 0.5 logical unit width pen", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      y += ySpacing;
      drawLineSet(drawingContext, ref y, penB05);
    }

    private void drawLineSet(DrawingContext drawingContext, ref double y, Pen pen) {
      var yL = y + lineOffset;
      glyphDrawerNormal.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "Plain, 1 pix y step", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x1 + i * 9, yL+i), new Point(x2 + i * 9, yL+i));
      }
      y += ySpacing; yL += ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerNormal.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "Plain, 1 pix y step, 0.5 pix x offset", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x1 + i * 9 + .5, yL+i + 0.5), new Point(x2 + i * 9, yL+i));
      }
      y += ySpacing; yL += ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerNormal.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "Plain, 0.5 pix y step", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x1 + i * 9, yL+i/2.0), new Point(x2 + i * 9, yL+i/2.0));
      }
      y += ySpacing; yL += ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerNormal.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "with Guidelines, 1 pix y step", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var xLeft = x1 + i * 9;
        var xRight = x2 + i * 9;
        var yLine = yL + i;
        GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(xLeft);
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(xRight);
        guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(yLine);
        drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(xLeft, yLine), new Point(xRight, yLine));
        drawingContext.Pop();
      }
      y += ySpacing; yL += ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerNormal.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "with Guidelines and 0.5 pix y offset, 1 pix y step", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var xLeft = x1 + i * 9;
        var xRight = x2 + i * 9;
        var yLine = yL + i;
        GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(xLeft);
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(xRight);
        guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(yLine + 0.5);
        drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(xLeft, yLine), new Point(xRight, yLine));
        drawingContext.Pop();
      }
      y += ySpacing; yL += ySpacing;
      glyphDrawerNormal.Write(drawingContext, new Point(x0, y), "with Guidelines and 0.5 pix x offset, 1 pix y step", FontSize, Brushes.Black);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var xLeft = x1 + i * 9;
        var xRight = x2 + i * 9;
        var yLine = yL + i;
        GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(xLeft + 0.5);
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(xRight + 0.5);
        guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(yLine);
        drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);
        drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, new Point(xLeft, yLine), new Point(xRight, yLine));
        drawingContext.Pop();
      }
    }
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Draws glyphs to a DrawingContext. From the font information in the constructor, GlyphDrawer creates and stores the GlyphTypeface, which
  /// is used everytime for the drawing of the string.
  /// </summary>
  public class GlyphDrawer {

    Typeface typeface;

    public GlyphTypeface GlyphTypeface {
      get { return glyphTypeface; }
    }
    GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;

    public float PixelsPerDip { get; }

    public GlyphDrawer(FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle fontStyle, FontWeight fontWeight, FontStretch fontStretch, double pixelsPerDip) {
      typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, fontStyle, fontWeight, fontStretch);
      if (!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No glyphtypeface found");

      PixelsPerDip = (float)pixelsPerDip;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes a string to a DrawingContext, using the GlyphTypeface stored in the GlyphDrawer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="drawingContext"></param>
    /// <param name="origin"></param>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <param name="size">same unit like FontSize: (em)</param>
    /// <param name="brush"></param>
    public void Write(DrawingContext drawingContext, Point origin, string text, double size, Brush brush) {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;

      ushort[] glyphIndexes = new ushort[text.Length];
      double[] advanceWidths = new double[text.Length];
      double totalWidth = 0;
      for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex<text.Length; charIndex++) {
        ushort glyphIndex = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[charIndex]];
        glyphIndexes[charIndex] = glyphIndex;
        double width = glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * size;
        advanceWidths[charIndex] = width;
        totalWidth += width;
      }
      GlyphRun glyphRun = new GlyphRun(glyphTypeface, 0, false, size, PixelsPerDip, glyphIndexes, origin, advanceWidths, null, null, null, null, null, null);
      drawingContext.DrawGlyphRun(brush, glyphRun);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it help to set `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` and/or `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` on the Window?

Comment: @Clemens: I had tried `SnapsToDevicePixels` before with no luck. I guessed these kind of options work only with `Visual`s, but I paint directly in `OnRender`. However, based on your suggestion I tried again (see edited part in my question) and it seems `EdgeMode` is an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve better looking straight lines in a notation application (staff lines, bar lines, note stems etc...) on displays with DPI settings other than 96, and came up with the following code. It really worked for me.

```
Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
double dpiFactor = 1/m.M11;
ScaleTransform scale = New ScaleTransform(dpiFactor, dpiFactor);
dc.PushTransform(scale);
...
...
dc.Pop();
```